# LWJGL ortho + translation matrix issue

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have used opengl for a long time and to setup a transform that will map sprite locations to the window coordinates I use the following ...

```
glOrtho(0, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, -1, 1);
```

then to position a sprite at a window coordinate I would use the following ...

```
glTranslate(100, 100, 0);
```

For the programmable pipeline I would do the same thing except instead of using glOrtho and glTranslate I would create matrix data structures and send them to shader uniforms

I am now using the java LWJGL library with a programmable pipeline and for some reason the transforms
have to be equivalent to

```
glOrtho(0, screenWidth, screenHeight, 0, -1, 1);
glTranslate(100, -100, 0);
```

if I do the programmable pipeline equivalent of

```
glTranslate(100, 100, 0);
```

the sprite goes of the screen. It appears that the y translation is reversed from what I am used to. Has anyone else worked with LWJGL and know about any issues that make it different from C/C++ opengl in this regard?

for reference in java I set up my ortho matrix with this code

```
float tx = -(right + left) / (right - left);
float ty = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
float tz = -(far + near) / (far - near);
float sx =  2 / (right - left);
float sy =  2 / (bottom - top);
float sz = -2 / (far - near);

matrix.m00 = sx; matrix.m10 =  0; matrix.m20 =  0; matrix.m30 = tx;
matrix.m01 =  0; matrix.m11 = sy; matrix.m21 =  0; matrix.m31 = ty;
matrix.m02 =  0; matrix.m12 =  0; matrix.m22 = sz; matrix.m32 = tz;
matrix.m03 =  0; matrix.m13 =  0; matrix.m23 =  0; matrix.m33 = 1;
```

and use the Matrix4f.translate to create the translation matrix. The matrices are sent to a projection and model uniforms and in the vertex shader the position is calculated as followed ...

```
gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
```

The matrix is setup to be transposed. I have also tried not transposed but I get an invalid transform when the matrix is not transposed.

**I found the problem it was an error in the above code**

instead of

```
float sy =  2 / (bottom - top);
```

it should be

```
float sy =  2 / (top - bottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original call to `glOrtho (...)` is atypical for OpenGL.

That is, you have your image projected so that Y=0 is the top. You are free to establish any projection you want, but if you are going to follow a text-book implementation of OpenGL matrix math you will generally need to swap the 3rd and 4th parameter in `glOrtho (...)`. Most books will assume that your ModelView matrix is right-handed and that the projection matrix inverts ***only*** the Z-axis to produce a left-handed coordinate system.

Since you are probably pretty happy with the projection you ***originally*** had, you just need to swap `top` and `bottom` in the function you are using to build your matrix the long way.